# How to authorize users to access GSI

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-index, aws-permissions

How do I authorizer all users to access a GSI? (In my case, the userIndex)

I can access the primary-index just fine. I successfully authorized all users to access the primary-index the following way:

[image]

---

Here I target the primary-index, which works just fine

[image]

---

Here I target the GSI, which doesn't work:

[image]

---

I tried adding dynamodb to my `AuthStack` at the two places you can see in the image below (to no avail). I doubt changing the AuthStack will do anything, since it is a lambda function that is making the `Put` request to DynamoDb (I might be wrong though).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

First of all, you are not supposed to write to a gsi, only read.

Secondly, when wantin gto query a gsi, you have to specify the `TableName` together with `IndexName`.

The following works

[image]